# Ember Handlebars iterating over global javascript array

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an array:
var eventTypes = [{name: x, value: y}, ... {...}...];
and I'm trying to iterate over this with handlebars.
I've tried

```
{{#each eventTypes
{{/each}}
```

but no luck. so, how can I iterate over a javascript array?

FIX: 
Made an Array controller that held the array within it.

```
Blocks.EventTypesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
content: eventTypes // controller eventTypes = global eventTypes
});
```

Comment: What's inside the `{{#each}}` block? Is anything printing? Errors?

Comment: Nothing. I'm looking more into the problem, and I believe it is because eventTypes is not within the context, so handlebars doesn't find the array. I tried Iterating over an array that didn't exist and nothing was shown and no error was thrown as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach that array to the controller which is backing the template, handlebars works within the scope of the controller, not the global scope.

```
App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend({
  eventTypes: eventTypes // controller eventTypes = global eventTypes
});
```

Comment: He didnt mention ember

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `this` to get to each object in the array as well.

```
{{#each eventTypes}}
    {{ this }}      
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Problem is... handlebars is not finding the eventTypes array. I have the array in events.js. How can handlebars find where this array was declared?

Comment: then we need more code - how are you trying to pull in the array - can you set up a fiddle?